# How to filter children components in Vue based on their component type?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am having trouble identifying children components in Vue.

I have this markup here:

```
<parent>
    <child-one>
    </child-one>

    <child-two>
    </child-two>

    <child-one>
    </child-one>
</parent>
```

The `parent` component is functional, so it is doing this:

```
render(createElement) {
    return createElement('div', this.$slots.default);
},
```

I want to iterate over `this.$children` and return an Array of VNodes kind of like this:

```
const matchingChildren = this.$children
    .filter(child => child.isChildOneType === true)

return createElement('div', {}, matchingChildren)
```

How do I do that?

What and where do I need to filter?

I'm pretty sure I can do it by setting a `type` prop on `child-one`, and then using `this.$children.filter(child => child.$attrs.type === 'special')`, but I want to filter them based on the fact they are `child-one` components.

I'm trying to make the example simple, but this is for tabbed pages, so I am not interested in conditional rendering. I'm trying to transform the markup into different DOM output, and I need to filter children of a specific type.

I have researched `$attrs` and `$options` as hooks that I could use, but if I use attrs, I need to add a prop to each component. I would like to avoid that since they are all of type `child-one`. I also can't seem to add a static property to `child-one`. The `$options` field is always empty.

Comment: What is wrong with `this.$children.filter(child => child.$attrs.type === 'special')`? If your child components  are siblings of other non-component markup, or those of you dont want filtered, then you have no choice but to set a prop indicating that they are the components that you need? Because in the browser there is no distinguishable difference between elements you made with a framework and those made otherwise

Comment: Thanks, that could be what I need. I'm just not sure. I was actually hoping a person would say something like that, especially about them all being generic nodes. I do like that as a solution because it means I can use any child and target them by adding a prop.

Comment: If you can convert your comment into an answer and give me a couple days to develop a bulletproof solution, I will mark it as correct unless someone else has a more wizard solution. I am looking for an idea like yours to give me confidence to pursue that direction.

Comment: I don't think I can convert it as an answer since I only questioned your example. You basically answered your own question, I just gave a benefit of the doubt why it's a viable solution. I do appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: But you're right, they are generic nodes and there is virtually no way for you to filter them out one by one without a specific flag/property to hold on to. At least no way that I know of.

Comment: Make an answer that details our comments here. I can't mark your comment as the answer, but I think you are correct, and the idea you are bringing forth should be an answer to my question. I can upvote your comments though :)

Comment: Sure lemme construct a nice answer that doesnt look like a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong or non-standard by setting a specific property to use as a filtering criteria such as

`this.$children.filter(child => child.$attrs.type === 'special')`

If your child components are siblings of other non-component markup, or those of you dont want filtered, then you have no choice but to set a prop indicating that they are the components that you need.

In the browser, the child nodes are plainly generic and cannot be properly isolated from one another without using some sort of identifier; such as a tag name, an id, attribute, or property. Nodes rendered via Vue, React, HTML, native JS whatsoever are all in all the same in the browser's perspective.

Since you can't use the component names like `child-one` because they will be rendered like normal HTML, you can just plainly add an attribute/v-attribute to each component wrapper on your Vue templates and simply filter them out like normal nodes once rendered.

```
<parent>
    <child-one>
         <div class="wrapper" componentType="1"></div>
    </child-one>

    <child-two>
         <div class="wrapper" :componentType="data.type"></div>
    </child-two>

    <child-one>
         <div class="wrapper" componentType="1"></div>
    </child-one>
</parent>
```

Or you can add attributes on the component themselves, which I have never tried before so I can't help you with that